# Exception "Security has not been configured for controller" is thrown when ActionNameSelectorAttribute is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-security

I have a problem with the *FluentSecurity* when the `ActionNameSelectorAttribute` is used on controller's action.

```
public static void Configure()
{
    var applicationConfiguration = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationConfiguration>();
    var superUserGroupName = applicationConfiguration.GetSuperUserGroupName();
    var userGroupName = applicationConfiguration.GetUserGroupName();

    var securityConfiguration = SecurityConfigurator.Configure(configuration =>
                                   {
                                       configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                                       configuration.GetRolesFrom(System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser);

                                       configuration.ForAllControllers().DenyAnonymousAccess().CachePerHttpRequest();
                                       configuration.ForAllControllers().RequireAnyRole(superUserGroupName).CachePerHttpRequest();
                                       configuration.For<Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController>().RequireAnyRole(userGroupName).CachePerHttpRequest();

                                       configuration.ApplyProfile<ProjectSecurityProfile>();
                                       configuration.ApplyProfile<ProjectsSecurityProfile>();
                                       configuration.ApplyProfile<RewecoSecurityProfile>();

                                       configuration.DefaultPolicyViolationHandlerIs(() => new HttpUnauthorizedPolicyViolationHandler());
                                   });
    securityConfiguration.AssertAllActionsAreConfigured();
}
```

When I run the application under the configuration above with the `AssertAllActionsAreConfigured` everything seems to be correct, no exceptions. But as soon as I call the action methods in the `ActualHoursAssignmentController` where the `HttpParamAction` is used , which is the class which inherits from `ActionNameSelectorAttribute` I get the exception.

*Security has not been configured for controller PDATA.Web.Controllers.ActualHoursAssignmentController, action ActionChoiceByNameAttributeValue Area: (not set) Controller: ActualHoursAssignment Action: ActionChoiceByNameAttributeValue*

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public static string ActionChoiceByNameAttributeValue
    {
        get { return "ActionChoiceByNameAttributeValue"; }
    }

    public override bool IsValidName([NotNull] ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                     [NotNull] string actionName, [NotNull] MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        if (actionName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionName");
        }

        if (methodInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("methodInfo");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actionName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("actionName");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(methodInfo.Name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("methodInfo.Name");
        }

        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (!actionName.Equals(ActionChoiceByNameAttributeValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

Usage of `HttpParamAction` attribute in `ActualHoursAssignmentController`

```
public class ActualHoursAssignmentController : PdataBaseController
{
    [HttpParamAction]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateAssignment(ActualHoursAssignmentViewModel vm)
    {

    }

    [HttpParamAction]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteAssignment(ActualHoursAssignmentViewModel vm)
    {

    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Because I didn't find the solution I *temporary* eliminate of usage `HttpParamActionAttribute`. Instead of that I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463204/53496) solution to call multiple buttons in the one *Form*, but the question persists, maybe it is a bug.

Comment: Are you using version 2 of FluentSecurity?

Comment: Yes I'm using version 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue in older versions of FluentSecurity with supporting Controller inheritance, see:

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Securing-controllers#securing-controllers-based-on-inheritance

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the inheritance. I'm using the latest version 2.1.0.